# using sed to repleace only one line in big xml

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I must replace only one Value in xml, for example:

```
<buildElement swFileKeyName="" name="name111" version="version111" hwUnit="xyz" nrOfBlocks="1" checksum="121241" fileLength="756" targetPath="/xyz/" path="/xyz/" compressed="" encrypted=""/>
  <buildElement swFileKeyName="" name="name222" version="_tralala.xyz" hwUnit="xyz" nrOfBlocks="1" checksum="1212431" fileLength="4973847" targetPath="/xyz/xyz/" path="/xyz/" compressed="" encrypted=""/>
  <buildElement swFileKeyName="" name="name333" version="_tralala.xyz" hwUnit="xyz" nrOfBlocks="1" checksum="-82304143" fileLength="842316" targetPath="/xyz/xyz/" path="/xyz/" compressed="" encrypted=""/>
  <buildElement swFileKeyName="" name="name444" version="_tralala.xyz" hwUnit="xyz" nrOfBlocks="1" checksum="1212411" fileLength="27294" targetPath="/xyz/xyz/" path="/xyz/" compressed="" encrypted=""/>
  <buildElement swFileKeyName="" name="name555" version="_tralala.xyz" hwUnit="xyz" nrOfBlocks="1" checksum="-128304118" fileLength="14427483" targetPath="/xyz/xyz/" path="/xyz/" compressed="" encrypted=""/>
  <buildElement swFileKeyName="" name="name666" version="_tralala.xyz" hwUnit="xyz" nrOfBlocks="1" checksum="121" fileLength="858646" targetPath="/xyz/xyz/" path="/xyz/" compressed="" encrypted=""/>
  <buildElement swFileKeyName="" name="name777" version="_tralala.xyz" hwUnit="xyz" nrOfBlocks="1" checksum="-1049134219" fileLength="8326950" targetPath="/xyz/xyz/" path="/xyz/" compressed="" encrypted=""/>
  <buildElement swFileKeyName="" name="name888" version="_tralala.xyz" hwUnit="xyz" nrOfBlocks="1" checksum="-2143131269" fileLength="1442128" targetPath="/xyz/xyz/" path="/xyz/" compressed="" encrypted=""/>
  <buildElement swFileKeyName="" name="name999" version="_tralala.xyz" hwUnit="xyz" nrOfBlocks="1" checksum="-35413144" fileLength="1850424" targetPath="/xyz/xyz/" path="/xyz/" compressed="" encrypted=""/>
  <buildElement swFileKeyName="" name="name122" version="_tralala.xyz" hwUnit="xyz" nrOfBlocks="1" checksum="-1040132184" fileLength="501444" targetPath="/xyz/xyz/" path="/xyz/" compressed="" encrypted=""/>
  <buildElement swFileKeyName="" name="name133" version="_tralala.xyz" hwUnit="xyz" nrOfBlocks="1" checksum="-173124317" fileLength="1149904" targetPath="/xyz/xyz/" path="/xyz/" compressed="" encrypted=""/>
```

and I must replace only one version value and one checksum value in one line.

I write this line:

```
cat Target_test.xml | grep name666| sed -r 's/checksum="([0-9]*)"/checksum="12112"/g' Target_test.xml
```

But this replace all + checksums, - checksum stay the same.
How to replace value for version and checksum in line name666

Comment: XML is not a line-oriented language; don't use line-oriented tools to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk '/name666/ && !done++{sub(/checksum="-?[0-9]+"/, "checksum=\"12112\"")}1' Target_test.xml
```

Comment: @Dzions change from `/checksum="[0-9]+"/` to `/checksum="[^"]+"/` and it should work for - numbers as well :)

Comment: Now its works, but i have one problem yet. If I must save in to this file Targer_Test.xml, now i saw this only in console, if i look at file (less targer_test.xml) then i see old value

Comment: You can do: `awk '/name666/ && !done++{sub(/checksum="-?[0-9]+"/, "checksum=\"12112\"")}1' Target_test.xml > _tmp && mv _tmp Target_test.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Using sed, you can precise on which line you want to work, using a regex:

```
sed -r '/name666/ s/checksum="[^"]+"/checksum="12112"/' Target_test.xml
```

On the line matching `name666` (`/name666/`) substitute `checksum="[^"]+"` with `checksum="12112"`.

Comment: almost, but script delete this line: fileLength="858646" targetPath="/xyz/xyz/" path="/xyz/" compressed="" encrypted=""

Comment: forgot about the greedy matching… Edited

Comment: after You editing sed don't work, look, in some line I have -value

Comment: @Dzions that's why I changed to `[^"]+` and not `[0-9]+`, it should work even for negative numbers.